# Close modal but the widget condition is same when open it again

Tags: flutter

Behavior of modal is always dispose when we close it. How to prevent the modal from dispose? So when i close it then open it again, the condition still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the modal from being disposed in Flutter, you can manage its state outside of the modal itself. Here are some tips on how to achieve this:

State Management: Use a state management solution (like Provider, Bloc, or setState) to manage the state of the content inside the modal.

Preserve State: Store the state of the modal's content in a variable that exists outside of the modal. This way, the state is preserved even when the modal is closed.

Pass State to Modal: When opening the modal, pass the preserved state back to it.

Comment: I have another solution, but i appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve using [Page Storage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorage-class.html) widget. I think it is the simple way and it can save the scroll position of page.

It can combine with @Ashutosh Sharma's answer based on your need.